# can a DFA with only final states be minimized?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I need to construct a DFA for a certain language with as little states as possible. 
so far my "best" solution contains 15 states. however, people claim it is doable in 7 states only. I tried for several days to come up with a smaller DFA but I failed miserably. So I thought I could try to minimize it. The only possible problem is, my DFA contains only final states(one of those is both initial and final). Is it possible to minimize it?

Comment: If your DFA contains no states other than final, then you can reduce it to a single-state DFA (which recognizes language $\Sigma^*$). If what you really mean is that only explicitly specified states are final, then the answer depends on your diagram of state-transitions.

Comment: only final states === DFA accepting $\Sigma^*$. I think you have a mistake in constructing your DFA.

Comment: Is it possible that your DFA has only final states, but some states do not have outgoing transitions with some letters? This is technically not a DFA, but often it is allowed. In that case, you can turn it into a "proper" DFA by adding a rejecting sink, and then use standard minimization.

Comment: Apply a minimization algorihm on your DFA or determine the Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes.